# Combine Range As CSV

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I combine range in a cell with comma-separated value (CSV) without writing one-by-one cell name?

I use concatenate formula, but it does not work because I can't add comma to separate every cell value.

Can anyone help? How to make formula with just write start column and finish column ?

Is this the sample, start column is 'P' and finish column is 'AC'.

Thus my range is: `('P'+rowNo+':AC'+rowNo)`.

Script:

```
sheet.getRange(rowNo,colRekapSiswa).setFormula('P'+rowNo+'&","&Q'+rowNo+'&","&R'+rowNo+'&","&S'+rowNo+'&","&T'+rowNo+'&","&U'+rowNo+'&","&V'+rowNo+'&","&W'+rowNo+'&","&X'+rowNo+'&","&Y'+rowNo+'&","&Z'+rowNo+'&","&AA'+rowNo+'&","&AB'+rowNo+'&","&AC'+rowNo);
```

Comment: There is no "formula" I know of that looks like what you have shown so I'm not sure what you are trying to do.  In javascript you don't use `&` ampersand to concatinate strings, simply use a `+` plus sign. "P"+rowNo+",Q"+rowNo+...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your goal. So here is a guess:

```
function to_csv(range) { 
  return range.join(',');
}
```

[image]

Which is actually the same as the native formula: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A1:C1)`

Or:

```
function the_weird_way_to_set_a_formula() { 
  var row = 10; 
  var formula = 'TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,' +
    [...'PQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''), ...'ABC'.split('').map(letter => 'A' + letter)]
    .map(letter => letter + row).join(',') + ')';

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('a1').setFormula(formula);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Yuri Khristich , it's work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but I'll give it a shot

```
function combineRangeValuesIntoOneCell() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(1,16,sh.getLastRow(),11).getValues();
  let o = vs.reduce((a,c,i) => {
    c.forEach(e => {
      a += e;
    });
    return a;
  },0);
  Logger.log(o);
}
```

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L | M | N | O | P | Q | R | S | T | U | V | W | X | Y | Z |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 | 16 | 17 | 18 | 19 | 20 |

```
Execution log
8:26:42 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:26:43 AM  Info    1155.0
8:26:44 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```